# Header display overlaps with adjacent Elements (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css

In my website, I have a layout like this:

```
<header>
    {Dropdown nav menu consisting of <nav>, <ul> and <li> }
</header>
<div>
    {content}
</div>
```

However, the header overlaps with the div, as if the div content were a background element with a lower z-index. I can fix this by changing the HTML:

```
<div>
    {Dropdown menu consisting of <nav>, <ul> and <li> }
</div>
<div>
    {content}
</div>
```

Why does this happen, and is there a way to get blocking behavior w/ the header element? I've toyed w/ the header's position, display, z-index, etc but haven't been able to have any effect.

Comment: header and div wihout any CSS are exactly the same ... share your CSS to be able to find the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp:

> Most browsers will display the  element with the following default values:

```
header {
  display: block;
}
```

Try removing/adjusting margin/padding from the `<nav>`, `<ul>` and `<li>` until you discover what is throwing your layout off.

Comment: Found the issue. Had a CSS class named  "header" and missed the . in its rule. That'll show me to be more careful w/ my naming. Thanks for the response!